# Android Application Showing Crosses over the Google Map

Tags: android, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I have developed 2 or 3 android application in which i used Google Maps. But today i find a problem. When i tap on the google map. Its showing multiple crosses over the map. Even every application those i have developed and have tested starts doing same thing. Can anyone suggest me some solutions.

Comment: are you tested on device currently?

Comment: yes i have tested on device or emulator both.

Comment: so i think In device you have a problem and on emulator its working correctly?

Comment: Are you using MapView or WebView (with JavaScript maps API) to display maps in your Android apps?

Comment: i have solve out this problem.